# Render to image buffer without opening a window

Tags: pyglet

is there any possibility to directly render/ draw into an image buffer using pyglet?

## Background:

I'm currently working on a project involving openai gym, which uses pyglet for rendering. The gym `env` exposes a [render method](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py#L80-L106), which returns rgb values of the window. From what I understand, pyglet extracts this representation from the opened window.

Unfortunately, my project involves a program which leverages python's `multiprocessing` package to spawn subprocesses containing instances of the openai gym `env`s.

As my operating system (OSX) prohibits UI actions from sub processes, python immediately crashes when I try to call the render method to obtain the rgb values.

Comment: I have the same problem could you find any solutions ?